# Selenium download file automatically without save dialog

Tags: java, selenium, save

When I click the download button, the website opens a save dialog. How can I make the browser download the file automatically without the dialog, or alternatively enter the path to the dialog?
This is what I tried but it didn't work:

```
 prefs.put("download.default_directory", FilesPath);
 prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads",1);
 prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
 chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
 chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-popup-blocking");
 DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
 cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
 cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);
 chromeOptions.merge(cap);
```

Comment: "download.prompt_for_download": False .I think is the prefs you need.

Comment: Or setup a dedicated browser profile and load driver with this profile.

Comment: download.prompt_for_download worked thank you!